# COMException thrown but not caught in C#

Tags: c#, comexception

I have the following code to trigger on a button click:

```
        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _BMDSwitcherConnectToFailure failReason = 0;
        string address = textBoxIP.Text;

        try
        {
            // Note that ConnectTo() can take several seconds to return, both for success or failure,
            // depending upon hostname resolution and network response times, so it may be best to
            // do this in a separate thread to prevent the main GUI thread blocking.
            m_switcherDiscovery.ConnectTo(address, out m_switcher, out failReason);
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            // An exception will be thrown if ConnectTo fails. For more information, see failReason.
            switch (failReason)
            {
                case _BMDSwitcherConnectToFailure.bmdSwitcherConnectToFailureNoResponse:
                    MessageBox.Show("No response from Switcher. Are you sure the IP is correct?", "Error");
                    break;
                case _BMDSwitcherConnectToFailure.bmdSwitcherConnectToFailureIncompatibleFirmware:
                    MessageBox.Show("Switcher has incompatible firmware", "Error");
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection failed for unknown reason", "Error");
                    break;
            }
            return;
        }

        SwitcherConnected();
    }
```

I noticed that when on a different machine, the program wouldn't run. I setup VS to break on the specific error and I get this:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

It throws this on the following line:

```
_switcherDiscovery.ConnectTo(address, out m_switcher, out failReason);
```

I'm struggling to figure out what this exception isn't caught by the code.

Comment: I assume you are using a external C/C++ dll. how did you imported it ?

Comment: The dll is just added through VS under References

Comment: @HansPassant No message box appears. I commented out the message boxes to check.

Comment: The issue is that you can't *see* the message box, commenting it out doesn't make it better.  You either need to prevent that ConnectTo() method from hanging the UI thread and causing the "Not Responding!" ghost window to appear.  Or you must specify the *owner* argument in the MessageBox.Show() call.  So that it doesn't pick the wrong owner, you would never want it to pick that ghost window :)

Comment: I had the same problem recently with my vsto outlook add in: catch(COMException) didn't catch the COMException, it bubbled up to the top level exception handler of .NET :(

Answer (score 0):

Check in Visual Studio debug options that you have this Exception type selected:

Debug - > Exceptions

Expand the CLRE (Common Language Runtime Exceptions)

Then expand - System.Runtime.InteropServices

Comment: I have the COMException enabled under System.Runtime.InteropServices. That's how I got VS to break on the exception, otherwise it works fine in VS. If you run the program after publishing it, it will fail on this COMException.